# Google Chrome Network Size explain

Tags: google-chrome

I am bit confused by the network status from Google Chrome developer panel.

[image]

**39.3KB** is the file size
what's this **2.9KB**?

anyone can explain?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Compression.**

The header on that column shows:

```
Size
Content
```

So I'm going to assume that Size (the generally smaller number) is the size of the file, as transferred (which usually *includes compression*), while Content is the actual amount of (*uncompressed*) content in the file.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, but how come the file size is in a huge different. is it because its cached?

Comment: Like I just said, it's compressed. If you look at the HTTP headers, you'll most likely see a `Content-Encoding: gzip` or something similar.